# Javascript smoothscroll does not work for some reason

Tags: javascript, html

Still working on my site: http://i333180.iris.fhict.nl/p2_vc/

There is a button for navigating down the page, the action is instant but smooth scrolling is much nicer.

So, I google around, tried a lot of things and the shortest script I found is this one, but I can't get it working:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

This is how I added to my code between:

```
<head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Button:

```
<body>
    <a id='button_down' href='#section' onclick="document.getElementById('moodvideo').pause()"><img src='scroll.png' alt='Scroll'></a>
</body>
```

I inspected the example site which was given and added it the same way to my html.
Ref inspected link: https://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/
But I can't make it work..

Also, I have another script, which needs the same action, after the end of a video.
Script for that is now:

```
<script>
    function videoEnded() {
        window.location.href="#section";
    }
</script>
```

This has to do the same thing; scroll nicely.

I hoped I explained it understandable, if not, I'd like to try it again.
Regards

**EDIT** Script isn't added to the online site because the script isn't working yet, if it would make it easier I could add it online.

**Update** Site is online with not working scripts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script works on the links on your live copy as intended, so I believe you mean your `videoEnd()` function.

The smooth scrolling script that you found only works for anchor tags (`<a>`).

As `window.location.href = "#section"` is not an anchor tag, it will not be affected by the script.

What you can do however is take the important bits of that script and use it in your `videoEnd()` function like so.

```js
function videoEnded() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#section").offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

**EDIT:**

The reason it is not working for you is because you're browsing the page using the `file://` protocol and the script source which links to jQuery is

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

Which uses the `//` relative scheme, which means that the browser will append the current browsing scheme, turning it into this..

```
file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

Which does not exist. If you specify `http://` it will work

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of `<script>` is much better:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( "a[href*='#']" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = event.target.href; 
        href = href.slice( href.indexOf( "#" ), href.length );
        $( "body" ).animate( {
           scrollTop: $( href ).get( 0 ).offsetTop
        }, 1000 );
    } );
} );
```